# What is the exact time of Ubuntu 14.04 release?

Tags: 14.04

Please tell me what time on April 17 14.04 becomes available.  I want to postpone buying a new laptop to the day before I can install 14.04 (at 09:00 UTC) in the hope that my old one is found.

Rob

Comment: This is not a duplicate to the linked question. The linked question asks for a time in general for all Ubuntu versions (which has an answer: there is no official time); this question addresses Ubuntu 14.04 in particular, which may have a different correct answer in case there is exception from the general rule...